# Filling area between semicircle and segment

Tags: tikz-pgf

I know that this is an easy question and although I have seen many examples do it I still don't get the method. I know it can be done with `\clip` and all those but I don't quite understand the concept behind

Anyway, here is what I am trying to do. We'll begin from this image. Here is a minimal working example to actually reproduce the image.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0, 0) -- (0, 4) -- (4, 4) -- (7, 0)--cycle;
\draw [dashed] (4, 4) -- (4, 0);
\draw [fill=black] (0, 0) circle (2pt);
\draw (0, 0) node[below]{$\Delta$};
\draw [fill=black] (0, 4) circle (2pt);
\draw (0, 4) node[above]{${\rm A}$};
\draw [fill=black] (4, 4) circle (2pt);
\draw (4, 4) node[above]{${\rm B}$};
\draw [fill=black] (7, 0) circle (2pt);
\draw (7, 0) node[below]{$\Gamma$};
\draw [fill=black] (4, 0) circle (2pt);
\draw (4, 0) node[below]{${\rm Z}$};
\draw [shift={(2.,4.)}] plot[domain=3.141592653589793:6.283185307179586,variable=\t]({1.*2.*cos(\t r)+0.*2.*sin(\t r)},{0.*2.*cos(\t r)+1.*2.*sin(\t r)});
\draw [dashed] (4, 4) -- (0, 0);
\draw [dashed] (0, 4) -- (2, 2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now, what I, eventually, want to achieve is to shade the area (s) bounded by the arc and the dashed segments. If you call the intersection point of ΒΔ with the arc E, the desired segments would be AE, BE.

That is my main problem and I don't realize what I should do in this situation. Could you please help my achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to draw the curved path twice, but the second time continue the path to the intersection with the delta-B line, and back to start, and fill this path. Below I did this `on background layer` (requires `backgrounds` library), so the fill doesn't cover any of the lines.

I also used the `intersections` library to calculate the intersection point E automatically, and I rewrote the code a bit, defining some coordinates first, and using these later.

Oh, and never use `\rm`, that has been deprecated for nearly 25 years now. Use `\mathrm{A}` instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate [label=below:$\Delta$] (delta) at (0,0);
\coordinate [label=below:$\mathrm{Z}$] (Z) at (4,0);
\coordinate [label=above:$\mathrm{B}$] (B) at (4,4);
\coordinate [label=above:$\mathrm{A}$] (A) at (0,4);
\coordinate [label=below:$\Gamma$] (gamma) at (7,0);

\draw (delta) -- (A) -- (B) -- (gamma) -- cycle;
\draw [dashed] (Z) -- (B);
\foreach \X in {A,B,Z,delta,gamma}
   \draw [fill=black] (\X) circle[radius=2pt];

\draw [name path=cos,shift={(2.,4.)}] plot[domain=pi:2*pi,variable=\t]({1.*2.*cos(\t r)+0.*2.*sin(\t r)},{0.*2.*cos(\t r)+1.*2.*sin(\t r)});
\draw [name path=straight,dashed] (B) -- (delta);
\draw [name intersections={of=cos and straight},dashed] (A) -- (intersection-1);

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\fill [blue!20,name path=cos,shift={(2.,4.)}] plot[domain=pi:2*pi,variable=\t]({1.*2.*cos(\t r)+0.*2.*sin(\t r)},{0.*2.*cos(\t r)+1.*2.*sin(\t r)}) -- (intersection-1) -- cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your code is very clear and I can follow it. Thanks for the `{\rm} ` tip.